# Web scraping of hotel name and its price?

Tags: html, python-3.x, parsing, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

I am a new learner of python and i am trying to scrape the name and price of particular hotel form goibibo. But every time it shows the output "None". I am not able to figure it out.

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

import requests
from requests import get



driver=webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\\hp\\Desktop\\New folder\\chromedriver.exe")

driver.get("https://www.goibibo.com/hotels/fihalhohi-island-resort-hotel-in-maldives-3641257667928818414/?hquery={%22ci%22:%2220200903%22,%22co%22:%2220200904%22,%22r%22:%221-2-0%22,%22ibp%22:%22v15%22}&hmd=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&cc=PF&reviewType=gi")

content=driver.page_source

soup=BeautifulSoup(content,"html.parser")

soup.prettify()


soup_name=soup.find("h3",class_="dwebCommonstyles__SectionHeader-sc-112ty3f-5 HotelName__HotelNameText-sc-1bfbuq5-0 hMoKY")


print(soup_name.txt)



Output:

> None
```

Comment: Can you put your code in a code block for readability?

Comment: @FriskySaga...i did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the hotel name code. Price depends on the room user chooses from hotel and there is no common price for hotel.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://www.goibibo.com/hotels/fihalhohi-island-resort-hotel-in-maldives-3641257667928818414/?hquery={%22ci%22:%2220200903%22,%22co%22:%2220200904%22,%22r%22:%221-2-0%22,%22ibp%22:%22v15%22}&hmd=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&cc=PF&reviewType=gi"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")
htag=soup.findAll('section',attrs={"class":"HotelDetailsMain__HotelDetailsContainer-sc-2p7gdu-0 kuBApH"})
for x in htag:
    print (x.find('h3').text)
```

**Note**: There is no need to use selenium webdriver if you just want to fetch the contents of webpage. Beautifulsoup itself does it for you